# How to store a value in memcached store from a rails worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

In my rails app, i want to store a value from the worker into the memcached and read it from the application controller. But in the worker i couldn't store the value as below

```
cache_store.write('db_status','down')
```

it says, undefined local variable or method cache_store.

How do i configure my worker to write into the memcache store.

i have set the cache store as below

```
config.action_controller.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```

in my environments config. I need to use  the same cache store in my worker too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Where does `cache_store` come from?

If you configure the internal [Rails caching feature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) to connect to Memcached, then you can use

```
Rails.cache.write("key", "value")
Rails.cache.fetch("key") { ... }
```

Comment: cache_store is the one i set in the production env file config.action_controller.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

Comment: i could read the value store into the memcached in the worker itself           Rails.cache.write('db_status','down')
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info("--------read in in workeri   #{Rails.cache.read('db_status')}")
but i couldnt do that in my application controller. it doesnt return the stored value

Comment: am not sure. if the worker and the rails app is using differnt cache store. why cant the value written by the worker read by the app.??