# How to access delayed_jobs resulting object in a controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am trying to learn how to use delayed_jobs in Rails, to offload a long-running Web request process, and store the results as a variable I can access later in my code. What is the best way to do this?

Within a method in my controller code, I am using:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(BuildDetail.new)
```

Then I define a class in lib/build_detail.rb (and require the file in the controller):

```
class BuildDetail

  def perform
    ...
    # some web request processing is here
    ...
    # the code returns the results of the web request processing as a variable:
    @newvar = ...
  end   

end
```

So here's my challenge, I need to be able to access the @newvar value to use in another controller method. I don't understand entirely how to reference the @newvar value. Since delayed_jobs processing is handled in the background, do I need to handle this with some sort of caching process, or is it possible to access the variable directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is store a single variable you could add it to memcache. It would be great choice if you already were using a cache in your Rails application. You could refer to this other question which talk about using memcache to store a variable which is later accessed in the controller.

[How to store a value in memcached store from a rails worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277666/how-to-store-a-value-in-memcached-store-from-a-rails-worker)

Comment: Would this work in a delayed job without Memcache - I mean using just the Rails.cache.fetch option, or do I need to use Memcache specifically?

Comment: Yep it would. dont have to use Memcache. You can go with the default rails cache I guess.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the default cache store doesn't work (memory_store), because delayed_jobs operates as a separate server process.

Comment: Ah I guess the problem might be because Rails might not allow an obvious way to access the default cache which is the file store. In which case an external in memory cache which can also be accessed from an outside process might be the right thing to do. Yep sorry about what I said earlier. That would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store that data in something like your database, mongo, redis etc. you won't get direct access because the job is executed in a separate process (and is destroyed once it is complete).